# Adjust plot height to map height when plotting matplotlib plot and geopandas map side by side

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, geopandas

I need to create a figure with 2 columns subplots, where the first subplot display a "normal" (non-spatial) plot, and the second is a map.

They should be side by side and I would need them to have the same height.

In the figure below, I'd like to adjust the height of the plot on the left to fit the height of the map on the right.

[image: normal plot and map subplots]

I guess the subplots might already be the same size, but as you can see, the border of the plot on the left is bigger than that of the map, and I'd like its height to be the same as the one on the right.

The code I am running is this one.

```
import numpy as np

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

ax1.plot(np.arange(10))
gdf.plot(ax=ax2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/273818/9518)!

```
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.0, wspace=0.0)
```

[image: subplots with equal heights]

**However**, if I need to adjust the figure size with `figsize`, this would "break" the map proportion, so I resize the figure preserving its ratio with:

```
RESIZE_FACTOR = 2.5
fig.set_size_inches(fig.get_size_inches()*RESIZE_FACTOR)
```